What is the reason why requesting to `api/user` is unauthenticated?
I still don't get it. It's been many days.
I am reading thoroughly this https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#spa-authentication.
The article states that they should be on the same top-level domain, which is fine. However, my current setup involves using Laravel as an API on one domain and ReactJS on a separate domain.
Locally, ReactJS is running on localhost:5173, while Laravel is running on 127.0.0.1:8000.
ReactJS
await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', { headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }})
  const response = await axios.post('/api/login', payload, { headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }});
  if (response) {
    const responses = await axios.get('/api/user', {
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    console.log(responses);
  }

the first two requests is okay, but the 3rd is unauthenticated
    const responses = await axios.get('/api/user', {
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

Why its unauthenticated?
The .env
SESSION_DOMAIN='.127.0.0.1:8000'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='localhost:5173'

cors.php
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],
'allowed_origins' => [http://localhost:5173'],
'supports_credentials' => true,

login
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($validated)) {
            $token = auth()->user()->createToken('auth_token');

            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token,
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
    }

What is the reason why requesting to api/user is unauthenticated?
Can you provide a solution?

Share the route defination of  /api/user.

Your api/user route is probaly behind the auth:sanctum middleware, and you never sent a token to that route after you got it from sanctum/csrf-cookie route. Please share route definitions.

You are using relative URLs in your axios requests there, but since you said these were actually cross-origin, I assume those .env values are translated into axios default request options that will be set somewhere? I guess you might need to include withCredentials with value true in those defaults as well - otherwise, this will not send any credentials (such as cookies) with the request.

The solution is that both Laravel and ReactJS should be under the same top-level domain. After reading a lot, I've understood that a top-level domain refers to like .com or .org, and my setup distinctly separates 'localhost' and the IP '127.0.0.1'.
To resolve the issue, I created a .conf file because I'm using Apache2, and I set both configurations on the same domain.
for reactjs
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName react.test

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/react/dist

    <Directory /var/www/react/dist/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

need to run pnpm run build
for laravel
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.react.test

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

